# How to initialize variable to solve C26495 c++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, var

this is my outside class code on creating Drink Menu. However, VS shows a warning
" C26495 : Variable MySturct3::drPrice " is uninitialized.

So, what is the problem here and how would I initialize the variable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

// This the list of variables. This is where the error shows in Visual Studio

```
struct MyStruct3
{
    string drinks[100]{};
    int drTimes = 0 ;
    double drPrice[100]{};
    
    MyStruct3() {};
};
```

// Class where the process occur

```
class drMenu
{
    MyStruct3 p;
    
    public:
```

// User will input the name of drinks

```
    void drinksMenu() {


        cout <<"\n\t\t[2] Drinks" << endl;
        bool repeat = true;
        bool dupl = true;

        while (repeat == true)
        {
            do {

                cout << "\n\t\tEnter Drinks [" <<p.drTimes << "]: ";
                getline(cin.ignore(), p.drinks[p.drTimes]);
            

                cout << "\t\tEnter Price: ";
                cin >> p.drPrice[p.drTimes];
                cout << endl;
                transform(p.drinks[p.drTimes].begin(), p.drinks[p.drTimes].end(), p.drinks[p.drTimes].begin(), ::toupper);
```

// Find similar name of drinks

```
                // Find the duplicae drinks
                if (p.drTimes > 0) {

                    for (int i = p.drTimes; i >= 0; i--) {
                        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

                            if (p.drinks[i] == p.drinks[j]) {
                                cout << "\n\t\tIt already exists. Please try again\n" << endl;
                                p.drTimes -= 1;
                                dupl = true;
                            }
                            else {

                                dupl = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                dupl = false;

            } while (dupl == true);


        cont:
            int choice;
            cout << "\n\t\t[1] Continue" << endl;
            cout << "\t\t[2] Stop" << endl;
            cout << "\t\t";
            cin >> choice;

            if (choice == 1) {
                p.drTimes++;
                repeat = true;
                dupl = true;
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                p.drTimes++;
                repeat = false;
                break;

            }
            else {
                cout << "\t\t Please Try Again" << endl;
                goto cont;
            }



        }
        
    }
```

// Display the drinks and its price

```
    void displayDr() {

        //drinksMenu( drinks, drPrice);
        system("CLS");
        cout << "\t\t****** Drinks Menu ******" << endl << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x <= p.drTimes - 1; x++) {
            cout << "\t\t[" << x + 1 << "] Php. " << p.drPrice[x] << "\t" << p.drinks[x] << endl;
        }
        
    }



};
```

Comment: You have excluded much of your code.  Show a minimal example that we can compile.  It looks to me like you might be using values from `drPrice` somewhere before ever initializing them.

Comment: Sorry sir, I've already changed it.